# Why are my YouTube videos no longer displaying?

Tags: jquery, html, razor, youtube-api

My dynamic YouTube-loading code had been working, but no longer does. Here's the pertinent jQuery:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
    var searchTerm = "";
    if ($("#inputText").val() !== "") {
        searchTerm = $("#inputText").val();
    } else {
        searchTerm = "jquery";
    }

    var urlYouTube = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq='" + searchTerm + "'&max-results=7&orderby=published&alt=json";

    $.getJSON(urlYouTube, function (data) {
        // Loop through each feed entry
        alert("made it into ewe toob");
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
            // Get the URL for the video
            var url = item.link[0].href;
            // Get the title of the video
            var title = item.title.$t;
            // Get the first 10 characters of date video was published or: YYYY-MM-DD
            var datepublished = item.published.$t.substring(0, 10);
            // Get the author name
            var author = item.author[0].name.$t;
            // Get the thumbnail image for the video
            var thumbnailURL = item.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
            // Construct the display for the video
            var text =
                "<br><a href='" + url + "'>" + title + "</a><br>" +
                    "Published: " + datepublished + " by " + author + "<br><br>" +
                    "<img src='" + thumbnailURL + "'><br>";
            // Append the text string to the div for display
            $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube").append(text);
        });
    });
});
```

This no longer populates my "You Tube" tab with videos. In fact, I never see, "made it into ewe toob".

I had been trying to display the results in an iframe, but because the results were no longer displaying, I went into debug mode, mashed F12, and saw:

```
Refused to display 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=platypus&max-results=7&orderby=published&alt=json' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. about:blank:1
```

So I changed the html from this:

```
<div id="duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube" style="min-height: 50vh">
    <iframe style="min-height: 100%;min-width: 100%" src="@urlYouTube"></iframe>
</div>
```

...to simply this:

```
<div id="duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube" style="min-height: 50vh">
    @urlYouTube
</div>
```

...and all I get in that tab is: "*http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=platypus&max-results=7&orderby=published&alt=json*"

IOW, I no longer get the console err msg, but I still don't get the videos. I also tried "@Html.Raw(urlYouTube)" Does anybody know why this is failing and how to fix this?

### UPDATE

It's still not working (alert doesn't even pop up and nag), even though the code is now this:

HTML

```
<div id="duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube" style="min-height: 50vh">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$.support.cors = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#duckbilledPlatypusTabs").tabs();

    //This doesn't seem to do anything...
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        var searchTerm = "";
        if ($("#inputText").val() !== "") {
            searchTerm = $("#inputText").val();
        } else {
            searchTerm = "jquery";
        }
```

. . .

```
var urlYouTube = "http://googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q='" + searchTerm + "'";
. . .            
});
        });
```

Comment: I don't know the razor templating language very well, but it seems that your code, which you say used to be working, is using the gdata feed as the source of the iFrame ... is that correct? If so, I'm not sure that should ever have been working, as the iFrame source needs to be the actual video URL, not the feed URL.  The feed URL is not configured to be displayable in an iFrame like a video URL would be (that's what the x-frame-options message is saying).

Comment: Thanks, but even without the iframe, as shown above, nothing happens.

Comment: Of course ... because without the iFrame, all you're telling your app to do is to put the value of the urlYouTube variable in as text, so it appears as a string (the template won't retrieve it and parse it for you). What you really want to do is to have your jQuery routine, which is already parsing the feed, get the value that the feed contents return for the url of the video and pass that to your template; for example, you can have an empty variable called iframeSrc, and then in your loop, set iframeSrc = item.link[0].href, and then use iframeSrc in your template instead of urlYouTube.

Comment: Well, I admit I'm confused; it worked fine for awhile (it wasn't pretty, but it worked well enough).

Comment: Like I said, I don't know a ton about razor templates but it's conceivable that the Youtube servers could have been allowing the feed content to be served up in an iframe before now, and razor could have been doing some internal magic to parse and extract what looked like a usable URL to serve as the iframe source. In any case, since you're using json you might be better served moving to v3 of the API anyway;have jQuery do an ajax get request to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q={whatever}&key={your_api_key} and parse through that--the results are easier to work with.

Comment: It's still a conundrum why the "alert" is not being displayed. Aside from that, though, after taking a fresh look at it, it makes sense that it doesn't work now, but I would think that it would with the "@urlYouTube" removed from the html.

Comment: Thanks for that tip; I wasn't aware there was a new and improved way to go about it.